# VideoView and content provider

Tags: android

According to the Android API for VideoView, it can load images (videos) from a content provider. Yet I can not find any examples of how to write a content provider that can do this.

Can you point me to such an example?

Thanks, Paul

Comment: override openFile and return ParcelFileDescriptor

Comment: pskink, that is a very interesting reply.  Can you please expand on it.  Override openFile from what class?  Who will be calling openFile()?  Some sample code, that works, would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: i mean your custom content provider,  override its openFile method